# Create COM objects in service

Tags: c++, windows, com, atl

Well. I had simple windows network application, which got some informatoin from network and then put it into COM object, that was created by third-party library (I have its sources).

Then I had to put this application inside Windows service. I implemented all the stuff to start and stop my application with Services Manager.

But then, when I try to *run* COM object in OLE/COM Object Viewer I got:

```
CoGetClassObject failed.
Server execution failed
CO_E_SERVICE_EXEC_FAILURE ($80080005)
```

In fact I'm a bit stuck with class hierarchy and architecture. Now I have my `NetworkApplication` class, which inherits from `Service` class. Where should I put `IClassFactory` class and who should inherit from `IUnknown`?

As I mostly use Unix, so don't doubt writing probably trivial things, as I got a mess in my head.

Comment: Many practical problems with implementing an out-of-process COM server in general, many more when you do it with a service.  The quality of the error reporting is just one.  The most basic failure mode here is that only a user with admin privileges that runs with UAC elevation can start a service.  Right-click Oleview.exe in Explorer and select "Run as Administrator" to at least eliminate that failure mode.

Comment: Yep, I do everything as an administrator. But I'm sure, I haven't finished development. And I'm mostly interested in architecture of the whole thing.

Comment: Hmya, nobody is going to write you a manual.  Unix sensibilities don't translate that well to Windows, security is not 0777 and a service is not exactly a deamon.  If you want to cut your teeth on COM then never bypass an in-process server first.

Comment: Typically there is little difference between implementing a COM server in its own out-of-process EXE versus a service. The main thing is that you have to define an AppID and associate it with the service and COM registrations in the Registry. This allows COM to start the service, if it is not already running, when the COM object is being instantiated by a client. You don't need admin rights to let COM do that (just to tweak the Registry). But it would be a good idea to have the service process call `CoInitializeSecurity()` to allow non-admins to access the COM object.

Comment: UAC may also be a factor here.  Even if you're logged on as an administrator, the OLE/COM Object Viewer won't necessarily be running with admin privilege.